# html5 localStorage save input fields into form on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where I want to save the data in local storage on keyup.

So if the user comes back to the form the data they have already filled in can be loaded from their localStorage.

I have the below [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v7QE/) which is storing the data in local storage as I want.

But I am having trouble pre populating the form with this data.

I know that closestID is undefined when I try and load it, how can I get the value for each id of Staff so that I can populate my form, or is there a better way?

```
    <form id="myForm">
        <div id="div-1" class="staff">
            <input type="name" name="name" value="Tim">
            <input type="number" name="age" value="18">
        </div>
        <div id="div-2" class="staff">
            <input type="name" name="name" value="Sarah">
            <input type="number" name="age" value="32">
        </div>
        <div id="div-3" class="staff">
            <input type="name" name="name" value="Brendan">
            <input type="number" name="age" value="48">
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
    jQuery("input").keyup(function () {
        var closestID = jQuery(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
        var staffArray = $("#" + closestID + " input").map(function () {
            return {
                "title": this.name,
                "value": this.value
            }
        }).get();
        //set that to localStorage
        localStorage["id-" + closestID] = JSON.stringify(staffArray);
    });

    var getFromStore = function (closestID) {
        //check if store values are null, if null, make store =[]
        var store = [undefined, null].indexOf(localStorage["id-" + closestID]) != -1 ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage["id-" + closestID]);
        //check if store is empty
        if (store.length != 0) {
            //loop over store if it aint empty and append the content into myStorage div
            for (var k in store) {
                var myTitle = store[k]["title"];
                var myVal = store[k]["value"];
                console.log('myTitle ' + myTitle);
                console.log('myVal ' + myVal);
                $("#" + closestID + " input[name='" + myTitle + "']").attr( "value", myVal );
            }
        }
    }

    getFromStore(closestID);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify which elements where used for storing the data. So you can use selector to find all elements which can be used as identification

```
$('#myForm > div')
```

Inside getFromStore you will iterate through div elements and try to find by ID whether localStorage contains the data.

```
var getFromStore = function ($storredElements) {

    $storredElements.each(function() {
        var sorred = localStorage["id-" + this.id];
        if (sorred) {
           var staffArray = JSON.parse(sorred);
           for (var k in staffArray) {
              var myTitle = staffArray[k]["title"];
              var myVal = staffArray[k]["value"];
              $("input[name='" + myTitle + "']", this).val( myVal );
          }

        }
    });
}
```

jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/d5Z8s/

Answer (score 3):

Nothing fancy:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');


//retrieve 
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    input[i].value = localStorage.getItem(i);
}

//store
jQuery("input").keyup(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        localStorage.setItem(i, input[i].value);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/3v7QE/4/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using you could try out [Phoenix](https://github.com/kugaevsky/jquery-phoenix) - it's a jQuery plugin for saving form fields values as the user types.

You can see it in action here: http://kugaevsky.github.io/jquery-phoenix/